# Jordan Curve Explanation

Tags: differential-geometry

Given any Jordan curve, how does one describe the set of all points entirely contained within the interior portion of the curve?  I would like a formal explanation and definition of those points other than the "interior of the curve."

Comment: The [Jordan curve theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem) tells us that the plane is divided into two disjoint regions. The interior is a *bounded* region. The exterior is *unbounded*. Saying much more than that is probably fairly difficult -- as difficult as, say, proving the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: I understand the Jordan curve theorem but I am just curious how one would refer to the set of all points on the interior of the curve in a formal way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formal way to go about it would be, let $\mathbb R^2$ be the Euclidean plane.  Let $C \subset \mathbb R^2$ be the Jordan curve, this is a continuous 1-1 image of a circle into the plane.

Then consider the path components of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus C$.  Let $P$ be a path component, then the closure $\overline{P}$ is either compact or non-compact.  Moreover, there are precisely two path components of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus C$, one has compact closure, and the other not.

Heuristically (and with some work this can be turned into a proof if $C$ is PL or smooth), given any point $p \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus C$, consider $\{ p + tv : t \geq 0 \}$ where $v$ is a unit vector.  "Generically" this ray intersects $C$ in finitely many points.  The parity of this number tells you whether or not $p$ is inside or outside of $C$.

Comment: So if it was odd or even would it be inside C?

Comment: Hint: Think about a very simple example to get the parity right.

Comment: So if the parity was odd, then it would be inside C, correct?